# Sufficient Conditions for the Commutator Subgroup to be a Component

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A group $K \ne 1$ is *quasisimple* if $K$ is perfect and $K/Z(K)$ is simple. For every subnormal subgroup $N$ of a quasisimple group $K$ either
$$
 N \le Z(K) \quad \mbox{ or } \quad N = K.
$$
A subnormal subgroup $K \unlhd \unlhd G$ which is quasinormal is called a [component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(group_theory)) of $G$.

**Proposition:** Let $Z$ and $E$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $Z \le Z(G)$ and $EZ/Z$ is a component of $G/Z$. Then $E'$ is a component of $G$.

> *Proof*: Since $Z \le Z(G)$ we have $E' = (EZ)'$, and since $EZ \unlhd\unlhd G$ also $E' \unlhd\unlhd G$. Moreover, by **(*)** below, $E'$ is perfect. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $E'$ and $\overline G := G/Z$. Then either
>   $$
>  \overline N = \overline E = \overline E' \quad \mbox{ or } \quad
>  \overline N \le Z(\overline E).
> $$
>   The first case gives $N \le E' \le NZ$ and thus $N(Z\cap E') = E'$. Hence $N = E'$ since $E'$ is perfect. The second case gives $[E', N] \le Z$ and
>   $$
>  [E', N, E'] = 1 = [N, E', E'].
> $$
>   The [Three-Subgroups Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma) yields $[E', E', N] = 1$ and thus $[E',N] = 1$, again since $E'$ is perfect. Hence $N \le Z(E')$, and $E'$ is quasisimple. $\square$

**(*)** Let $N$ be an abelian normal subgroup of $G$. If $G/N$ is perfect, then $G'$ is perfect.

I understand everything of this proof, except the line:

> The first case gives $N \le E' \le NZ$ and thus $N(Z\cap E') = E'$. Hence $N = E'$ since $E'$ is perfect.

In general for $A,B,C\le G$ just $A(B\cap C) \le AB \cap AC$ holds, so a "distributive" rearrangement like $N(Z\cap E') = NZ \cap NE' = NZ \cap E' = E'$ is not valid? And secondly, why $N = E'$? If I suppose that $E'$ is perfect, all I can get is $E' = (E')' = (N(Z\cap E')' = N'$ (the last equality when I look at the commutators), so $E' = N'$, but why should $N$ be perfect too, which is equivalent with $E' = N$ in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E'=E'\cap NZ$ now we can apply Dedekind rule as $N\leq E'$ $(1)$,

$E'=E'\cap NZ=N(E'\cap Z)\implies E'=N'$ then $E'\leq N$ by $(1)$, $E'=N$.